# Efficient stable PriorityQueue implementation needed

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, priority-queue

I have an implementation of A-* for a board game that originally used [Eric Lippert's PriorityQueue implementation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/10/path-finding-using-a-in-c-3-0-part-three.aspx) using SortedDictionary, but the performance is unsatisfactory for my board size.

Using a MinHeap implementation of PriorityQueue gave me a *2 speed-up on long diagonal paths (5-6 seconds down to 2-3 seconds); but then I realized it provided an unstable sort. For this application I require a stable sort.

Are there any well known implementations of PriorityQueue that combine the efficiency of a MinHeap, but provide a stable sort in the way that SortedDictionary does?

**Update:** Additional details from comments below:

- PriorityQueue operations requried: Enqueue(), Dequeue() & Count;
- On each iteration of A-*: IsEMpty & Dequeue() called once each, Enqueue() called 6 times;

**Resolution:**

While the complexity of `SortedDictionary<uint,Queue<TValue>>` and `MinListHeap<KeyValuePair<TPriority,TValue>>` are the same, the additional code complexity of maintaining insertion order seems to be a constant tme penalty. This may not be definitive, but I was looking for low-hanging fruit at this stage of refinement.

Further, as I thought about the problem more, I realized that stability was only required on short paths, not on long ones; so it was possible to select the required implementation of PriorityQueue on entry to FindPath() based on the initial heuristic estimate of the distance from start to goal.

Comment: Stable sort algos are rare and generally less efficient. Nothing is for free. Can't you tweak your definition of equality?

Comment: Could you use the existing implementation, but add to your keys an index value to ensure that keys with equal priority sort in the right order? (If you see what I mean) [EDIT] Which is what Henk means too, I think.

Comment: @Henk: Possibly, and I can build a pre-computed road-map also; but if an easy * 2 was available here then I could start with that. My goal is to get the long diagonals down to around 0.1 or 0.2 seconds if possible.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: The complication in doing that is that I have already got a 2-part key: 16 bits for the estimate, and 16 bits for an alignment preference on the hex-grid which also fragments the priorities. And my algorithm courss are both > 30 years ago, so I am a bit rusty on this stuff.

Comment: When you say "efficient" which operations do you have in mind?  Specifically, I am asking because insertion into MinHeap is **log n**, but into an array which is to be sorted is **n log n** or n depending on how you implement this.  In other words, which operations do you need to support efficiently?

Comment: @angelatlarge: MinHeap's performance is fine, but it doesn't preserve insertion oder in the PriorityQueue. SortedDictionary preserves the insertion order, but consumes much more CPU on the long paths. I am wondering if there is a PriorityQueue implementation that will both give me better performance than the SortedDictionary, and preserve insertion order.

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens But again, which priority queue operations do you need to be efficient?  Just `removeMax`/`removeMin`?  `insert`?  Just `peekMax()`/`peekMin()`?

Comment: Ok, and it is important that **all** of those be efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a comment, but it got too long.  So here goes:

I couldn't find the implementation of the priority queue as a sorted dictionary following the link you suggested, but Googling around suggests that this priority queue is implemented using binary search trees. **If** that is the case, it would seem like these are not self-balancing search trees, as I don't understand how a 2x improvement could result by replacing the BST with a heap.  A self-balancing BST gives you guaranteed log(n) performance on `insert()` and `find()`. The same is true for `deque()` (=`removeMin()`): it should also be a *guaranteed* log(n): you just go left until there are no more left children.

Ok, so we have log(n) for every operation for the binary search tree (BST). What about the heap?  Well, for the operations you are looking at, it is the same: `removeMin()` (=`dequeue()`) returns the node with the highest/lowest key (this is O(1)), but then places the last node in the initial spot and sinks it down by comparing it with its children recursively. This requires 2 compares at each level, and usually involves log(n) levels. So 
`removeMin()` is a O(log(n) ) operation. What about `insert()` (=`enqueue()`)?  Here, in the usual implementation we place the new item at the end, and then float it up, by comparing with its parents. In the usual case this takes 0.5*log(n) operations, i.e. O( log(n) ). This means both the BST and the heap should have log(n) performance on enqueue() and dequeue(). And both data structures should have O(1) performance on `isEmpty()`.

This reasoning, if correct, suggests one of the following:

- the constant factors in the BST implementation dwarf the constant factors in the minHeap priority queue
- the BST used is not self-balancing.

One might also think that `0.5*log(n)` of the heap on `insert()` might be better than BST `insert()`, however, the BST insert is actually also usually about `0.5*log(n)` in reality, so this can't be it, I think. Constant factors are plausible: *if* minHeap is implemented as an auto-resizing array (or better yet a non-resizing array) then the minHeap may not need to allocate extra storage space on `enqueue`, which the BST implementation must do.

It is also possible that the BST is not self-balancing. In this case, in the worst case, either the `dequeue()` or the `enqueue()` will take O(n) time, depending on the order in which the items are added. So this would be something to look at.

**EDIT 1**: The way regular BST implementation can be made to be stable is by adopting a convention that if we insert nodes with identical keys, the new node becomes (say) the right child of the identically-keyed node. This way the first node with the same key will be dequeued. With self-balancing BSTs this might take a bit more work, as rotation may violate this desired invariant. In this case, I guess what I would do (thinking of [red-black trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), not [AVL trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree)) is when rotating two nodes A and B I would check whether their keys are, in fact identical same, and if so, switch the node data while maintaining the node structure.  But there may be better solutions for this problem.

**EDIT 2** According to [this acticle](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2011/10/05/sorteddictionary-and-sortedlist/), SortedDictionary is in fact based on red-black tree. This in turn suggests either a bug in the implementation (doubtful but not unheard of) or constant factors as a culprit.

Comment: Oops! I have now corrected the link. I am also left thinking that the difference is in the constant factor, but *2 seems high.